# C++ Cli implementation of managed event

Tags: events, c++-cli

I'm want to implement a managed interface in cli/c++ component. Let's say my interface has an event like this:

```
public interface IManagedInterface
{
   event EventHandler<ServiceCollectionChangedEventArgs> ServiceCollectionChanged;
}
```

My cli component exists of header and .cpp file. In my header I defined the event and a private method to raise it.

```
ref class NativeImplementation : public IManagedInterface
{
  public:
     virtual event System::EventHandler<ServiceCollectionChangedEventArgs^>^ ServiceCollectionChanged;

  private:
    void RaiseServiceCollectionChanged(System::Type^ type, ChangeAction action);
};
```

In my .cpp file I want to implement the raise method and that's where im struggling.

```
void NativeImplementation::RaiseServiceCollectionChanged(Type^ type, ChangeAction action)
      {
        EventHandler<ServiceCollectionChangedEventArgs^>^ local = NativeImplementation::ServiceCollectionChanged;
        if (local != nullptr) {
          local(this, gcnew ServiceCollectionChangedEventArgs(type, action));
        }
      }
}
```

I'm used to do the checks above before raising the event, but the compiler complains "error invalid use of event member". Can anyone help me? Do I even need these checks in c++?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, the idiom for raising an event is to copy the event to a local variable, check that for null, and then call the handlers using the local variable, rather than re-reading from the event object.

```
// C# Idiom
void RaiseEvent()
{
    EventHandler<Whatever> handler = this.MyEvent;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new Whatever());
}
```

You're obviously trying to follow that same pattern in C++/CLI, but it's not necessary. When you access the `event` member of your class, it will do that idiom for you. All you need to do is call the event like a function, and it'll be done correctly.

```
// C++/CLI *only*. This will cause bugs if you do this in C#.
void NativeImplementation::RaiseServiceCollectionChanged(Type^ type, ChangeAction action)
{
    this->ServiceCollectionChanged(this, gcnew ServiceCollectionChangedEventArgs(type, action));
}
```

Under the hood, C# defines two methods for each event member: `add` and `remove`, which are called when `+=` and `-=` are used. The idiom above is necessary because there's no built-in null check, and the local copy is needed in case the event is modified on another thread between the null check and actually firing the event. C++/CLI defines three methods: `add`, `remove`, and `raise`, and the `raise` method implements the null check and local copy, the same thing as C# requires each developer to implement themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Your event is an instance member not static member, so you should scope your event name with *this* keyword in your raise method (or not scope it at all).

```
EventHandler<ServiceCollectionChangedEventArgs^>^ local = this->ServiceCollectionChanged;
```